# supremum and limsup of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

I have difficulty understanding what is sup$X_n$ and what is limsup $X_n$, for $X_n$ as s sequence of random variables.

Does sup$X_n$ mean for all $\omega$ in the domain of $X_n$, sup $X_n(\omega)$. So sup$X_n$ is a different number for each $X_n$. And $\limsup X_n$ means for each $\omega$, we find sup$X_n(\omega)$ for each n, and set n to infinity.

Then what does limsup$\frac{X_n}{logn}=1$ mean?

Answer (score 6):

No, the supremum is over $n$. For each $\omega \in \Omega$,
$$(\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n)(\omega) := \sup\{X_n(\omega):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
Note that $\sup_n X_n$ is still a random variable!

Similarly, $\limsup X_n$ is a random variable. For each $\omega \in \Omega$,
$$(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n)(\omega) := \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega).$$
That is, for a fixed $\omega$, you have a sequence of real numbers $\{X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega),\ldots\}$, and I assume you know the definition of limit supremum of a sequence of real numbers.

$X_n / \log n$ is again a random variable, so you can apply the reasoning above to talk about $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_n}{\log n}$.

Comment: So sup$X_n$ means, for each $\omega$, the supremum of the sequence of $X_n(\omega)$ over all n. I'm still a little confused by the definition of limsup$X_n$, could you please elaborate it more? Thank you.

Comment: @Rann I've added a sentence.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @angryavian are some days that I'm struggling on understanding the Sup of a sequence of r.v.. I try to imagine an expressive example: Event: throw a die,  sequence of r.v. $(X_n) = 1/n$ when $\omega=1,2$; $(X_n) = \frac1{2n}$ when $\omega=3,4$ and $(X_n) = 0$ when $\omega=5,6$. In this case the supremum is 1/n, and for checking it I have to analyse the value of the sequence for each $\omega$. Therefore I can see that for  $\omega =1,2$, the maximum value that the sequence take is 1/n, while for  $\omega=3,4,5,6$ the value is lower then 1/n. so sup=1/n.Could you tell me if I understood it well?

Comment: @Alberto__ I feel that you are misunderstanding quite a few things. It would be better to ask a new question so that people can help clarify things for you.

Comment: @angryavian here it is the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383958/understanding-the-supremum-of-a-r-v-with-an-example. I would be grateful if you also help me at understating this point. Thank you

Comment: @angryavian whats the deal with using "essential supremum"? Does the above definition not work for uncountable sequences?