# Understanding $sup E[X_n]$ and $E[\sup X_n]$ with an example

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

Mentioning the definition of Supremum offered in [supremum and limsup of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469896/supremum-and-limsup-of-random-variables/1469910#1469910) , we have:
For each $\omega \in \Omega$,
$$(\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n)(\omega) := \sup\{X_n(\omega):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I tried to imagine an expressive example:

Event: throw a die.

$(X_n)=\frac1n$ when $\omega=1,2$;

$(X_n)=\frac1{2}$ when $\omega=3,4$;

$(X_n)=0$ when $\omega=5,6$.

Then we can compute $$E[X_n]:\frac1n\frac13+\frac1{2}\frac13+0\frac13=\frac3{6}=\frac1{2}$$

Therefore: $\sup_n E[X_n]=\frac12$. For computing $E[\sup X_n]$ instead we have:

$\sup_n X_n(\omega)=1$ if $\omega =1$ or $2$,

$\sup_n X_n(\omega)=\frac 1 2$ if $\omega =3$ or $4$

and $0$ if $\omega =5$ or $6$

Therefore $E[\sup X_n]=1\frac13+\frac12\frac13+0\frac13 =\frac36=\frac12$

Could someone tell me if this reasoning is it correct?

Comment: You chose  bad example and got the same value. It is not true that $E\sup X_n=\sup X_n$ in general. You get equality in your example becasue the seqeunce $(X_n)$ is decreasing.

Comment: @KaboMurphy ok I get it, but anyway was it correct how I computed $EsupX_n $ and $supEX_n$?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct.